# How to animate shapes on top of a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, gis, leaflet

I'm new to leaflet, looking for some advice.

I'd like to create an animation of a marker of some sort (for example, an html5 filled arc or shape) to replay GPS tracks on a map.  I may want several animated markers and I want to stay flexible with the behavior and performance.  Can anyone recommend a good way to go about creating this type of animation?

It looks like I could create a canvas layer (L.TileLayer.Canvas) and draw on it using a technique for linear animation (e.g. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/), but I'm not yet sure if this works, or if I need to call redraw() and how the performance would be.  Or I could try and make customer markers and move them by setting the lat/lon on them at some interval.

Has anyone come across this and can recommend a solution (above ideas or other)?  Ideally as I change zoom levels, the animation will "scale" and have good performance.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar.  Did you find something that worked?

Answer (score 1):

The RaphaelLayer plugin lets you create some pretty fancy animations:

http://dynmeth.github.com/RaphaelLayer/

Answer (score 1):

yes there are a couple of ways to approach the problem...
drawing onto an interactive map is challenging because you need to recalculate your position on pan and zoom events; in addition to managing your actual animation.

This is an excellent example using the D3 library to manage the animation in a continuous loop, you may be a able to modify the code for multiple animations.
http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/

If you want a little more of the knuts and bolts of how the drawing process works then this project might be a better starting point
http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/11114288#L.CanvasOverlay.js
This grabs the overlay pane (a leaflet canvas which you can draw on) and... draws on it...

and you will absolutely want to check out this link which describes the [drawing](http://blog.sumbera.com/2015/08/14/svg-fast-scaled-overlay-on-leaflet-1-0/) process for an interactive map